# rowIndex not updating primeng datatable

Tags: angular, primeng

I have `p-datatable` of `primeng`. After I remove certain object from `datatable-row`, the `rowindexes` are not updating.

Any workaround or solution???

Comment: what is the code you have done. update them to post

Answer (score 3):

This issue was closed and the [fix](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/2432#event-1097208685) will be available on release [4.0.2](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/milestone/63) of primeng.

Comment: It's not working in this version as well. Can you please suggest some other workaround